How should I handle a valid chat flag when a suspension isn't warranted?
I've already read through A guide to moderating chat, and this isn't covered there.
For example, a user might post something slightly over the line that ought to go, but has now returned to productive conversation.
What's the preferred way to handle chat flags when they are right, but I don't think the user should be suspended?
Here are some possibilities:

Decline the flag, move the message to a Trashcan room
Approve the flag, and then immediately unsuspend the user (for mods)


Another possibility: decline the flag, verbally warn the user, do nothing with the message, add annotation to user's profile noting that you did this.  This may be useful in cases where things have gotten heated, but the responding moderator feels it can be de-escalated, and deleting messages would make the resulting discussion make no sense.  My understanding is that there is no feedback to the flagger whether the flag was accepted or declined, so the only consequence is whether the message is deleted and the user auto-suspended.
